# Find the value of $k$ from the following Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hello beautiful community, how are you? I have a problem that I would not be understanding. Given $B = \{(1, −1,0), (0,1, −1), (0,0,1)\}$ a base of $\mathbb R^3$ and let $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ a linear transformation such that

$$M_{EB}(f)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4\\0&5&5\\2&4&8\end{pmatrix}$$

If $Im (f) = ⟨(k^2,6, k); (3, −6, k^2)⟩$, then $k$ is equal to:
(and they give me 4 options)
a) $\ 2$ 
b) $-2$ 
d) $\ 3$ 
c) $-3$

The first thing I don't understand is what you mean by $EB$ as a sub index in the matrix. Can I directly extract the Image of the columns of that matrix?
If I take the images directly from the columns of the matrix, it doesn't give me any of the options, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: $M_{EB}(f)$ is the matrix expression of the linear map $f$ when one considers the basis $E$ in the domain and the basis $B$ in the target.

Comment: @mfl so none of the answers is correct, or at least it doesn't give me any of them. Could it be that this wrong? or that I am doing it wrong? haha

Comment: @mfl because I have done that and it gives me that the linearly independent vectors in the matrix are (1,0,2) (0,5,5) and I cannot find k with those two: /, I am confused I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_{EB}$ is the representative matrix of $f$. Let me call it $\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal B}(f)$. I'll show you a general method to do this kind of exercises.
The columns of the matrix are the ordered coefficients of the linear combination of the vectors of $\mathcal B$ which express the images of the canonical vectors of $\mathcal E=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.
So, we have that $$f(e_1)=b_1+2b_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$f(e_2)=2b_1+5b_2+4b_3=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\5\\-5\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$f(e_3)=4b_1+5b_2+8b_3=\begin{pmatrix}4\\-4\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\5\\-5\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
We can observe that $f(e_3)=2f(e_1)+f(e_2)$ and it's easy to see that $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$ are linearly independent $\implies\text{dim(Im}(f))=2$ and $\text{Im}(f)=\langle f(e_1),f(e_2)\rangle$.
If you want to find $k$ you have to take a particular linear combination of the vectors $f(e_i)$ in order to find vectors that can be express as you wrote in the exercise (for example the subspace generated by $f(e_2)$ is the same of $2f(e_2)=(4,6,-2)=((-2)^2,6,-2)$ and you can do something similar to find the other vector).

Comment: but I don't understand, why would you do the whole account for the other vector? if there it gives you (4,6,−2)=((−2)2,6,−2) so... k is -2 , right ?  pls can you explain me?

Comment: Exactly, the exercise is asking you to find two vectors in the image of $f$ (you could obtain them also taking any linear combination of $f(e_i))$ in the form $(k^2,6,k),(3,-6,k^2)$. Are you sure there is a $-6$ in $(3,-6,k^2)$? Anyway, I hope that the theory behind the problem is clear now.

Comment: why do you ask me that? you mean if the exercise copy it right?. it is Im (f) = ⟨(k ^ 2,6, k); (3, −6, k ^ 2)⟩. But now I am in doubt, why couldn't it be 2 ? I mean the answer a)2